# Web Scraping WSJ Corn Prices With Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup in Python to web scrape data for corn commodity prices. Here's my code just sampling how to maybe get the data:

```
import urllib2
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

url="http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-cashprices-20170320.html"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
soup.title
f=open('corny.txt', 'w')
commodity = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"text"})
print commodity[51]
commo = commodity[51].string
print commo
#Corn, No. 2 yellow. Cent. Ill. bu-BP,U (success!!)
f.write(commo)
corndate = soup.findAll("span")
print corndate[16]
cdate = corndate[16].string
print cdate
f.write(cdate)
price = soup.findAll("b")
print price[46]
pricey = price[46].string
print pricey
f.write(pricey)
f.close()
```

The problem is that I need to do this for every day from 2005 to the present day, but the order of tags changes, so I can't keep the same code (e.g. for one day the 51st attrs={"class":"text"} is for Corn, but for another day a week later it is for something like cotton. I need code written so that by text file outputs the date and price (Wed Price) for CORN ONLY (Corn, No. 2 yellow. Cent. Ill. bu-BP,U).

Additionally, the URL structure seems more complex than I can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract by `tr` tag and then search for which element is containing string `"Corn, No. 2 yellow"`. Then get the price from there.

```
url="http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3020-cashprices-20170320.html"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


corndate = soup.find_all("span")
cdate = corndate[16].string
print (cdate)

corn_name = ""
corn_price = ""

corn_info = soup.find_all("tr")
for corn in corn_info:
    text = corn.get_text()
    if(text.find("Corn, No. 2 yellow") > -1):
        text = text.replace("\n\n", "\n", 10)
        text = text.strip("\n")
        all_text = text.split("\n")
        corn_name = all_text[0]
        corn_price = all_text[3]
        break

file = open("Corn Info.txt", "a")
file.write(corn_name + "\n")
file.write(corndate + "\n")
file.write(corn_price + "\n")
file.close()
```

Comment: How do I get this to print in my text file again and again for different URLs?

Comment: Just as you wrote in your text file. I'm updating the code, just wait a bit.

Comment: @SierraThomander Do you want to create different text files for different dates ?

Comment: No, one text file for all the dates. If it's better, you could just do it for the first day of the month for each year (2005-2017). Thank you!

Comment: That looks great, thank you. If I want to do it for multiple dates (and thus multiple URLs) is there an option for that? Or should I do it all manually?

Comment: You need to go through different URLs of different dates and collect the informations.

Comment: Or you can change the URL according to the date for which you want the information. Have a look at the URL and you will find the way.